# Run Docker Cloud

Tags: docker, docker-cloud

Im new in Docker, I tried to run Docker Cloud with the command:

```
# docker run dockercloud/cli
```

When I run the docker image nothing happens, I can only see this:

```
usage: docker-cloud [-h] [-v]
                    {action,container,event,exec,login,node,nodecluster,repository,run,service,stack,tag,trigger,up}
                    ...

Docker Cloud CLI

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -v, --version         show program's version number and exit

Docker Cloud CLI commands:
  {action,container,event,exec,login,node,nodecluster,repository,run,service,stack,tag,trigger,up}
    action              Action-related operations
    container           Container-related operations
    event               Get real time Docker Cloud events
    exec                Run a command in a running container
    login               Please use "docker login" to log into Docker Cloud
    node                Node-related operations
    nodecluster         NodeCluster-related operations
    repository          Repository-related operations
    run                 Create and run a new service
    service             Service-related operations
    stack               Stack-related operations
    tag                 Tag-related operations
    trigger             Trigger-related operations
    up                  Create and deploy a stack
```

Which is the command to run docker cloud to see the web administration page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go to the administration page, go to https://cloud.docker.com/

The dockercloud/cli is an image container the docker-cloud cli tool in case you want to do admin tasks via a CLI instead of via the web admin.

Comment: So, The docker cloud is a private tool, i can't installed in my own sertver rigth?

Comment: docker cloud is a hosted service, yes. There is another product called Docker Datacenter that you can install on your own server.